# angularjs adding "input-txtgray" only to one field

Tags: angularjs, angular

In my angularjs component.ts file I have code that looks like

```
 this.inputmy_input_name[id] = 'input-txtgray';
```

what this does is that it adds input-txtgray class to form element my_input_name

but the problem is there are 2 or more form elements with the same name and I need to change only one (the one next to the element that triggered the call), I suppose thats what the id is supposed to do but doesn't.

I am new to Angular and I am not sure if this is something that is standard to Angular or is this something that is in the code somewhere?

Edit: The elements are autogenerated using other code and I can't change the elements without extensively editing the rest of the code and right now I do not wish to do so.

Any help highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing this way, you can use ngClass.
Read abt it here: [angular.io/api/common/NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

```
<some-element [ngClass]="{'input-txtgray': true}">
</some-element>
```

In the place of **true**, you can put a boolean variable(initially **false**) and trigger it **true** on API call